# Exception A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp, wireshark

We get this Exception "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond" when reading from a socket (.NET Socket). This happens once in a while and we see that the sender sends an 8000+ bytes package. With the MTU of 1500, this message is split up into 6 separate messages. In Wireshark, we see that the last frame is sent with a delay of 19 - 29 seconds when the exception occurs. Normally the delay between the frames is approx 0.01 - 0.03 seconds. We are really puzzled about what could cause the last delay. We see no issues in the load of the CPU of the sender (steady at around 27%).

On this Network, there are 2 of these senders, which send these 8000+ bytes frames. And both have this issue randomly.

[image: Wireshark]

We expect to have a more constant delay between the messages and to receive all the frames without a timeout. We are a bit out of suggestions on what could cause this delay.

Comment: What are the socket settings? Have you been playing around with [Socket.NoDelay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.nodelay?view=net-7.0#remarks) ?

Comment: Which socket settings do you mean? We implement a server that listens to port 32022 which is open for the communication.

Comment: Is the sender authored by you, too?

Comment: Yes, the sender is authored by us. Also, we don't have NoDelay enabled but just defined it to true and now we see what happens.

Comment: @Fildor the No-Delay does not seem to fix the issue. The last packet every now and then gets delayed about 30 seconds or so and then the socket gives the error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Yeah, that was just a shot into the blue. I guess you'll have to take a deep dive into the sender side. I wouldn't think it is something on the way. But talking of that: are there any (Smart-)Switches, Hubs, Proxies, ... in between?

Comment: @Fildor in the network, we only have the 2 senders, 1 receiver, and 1 switch from Netgear. That is all.

Comment: @Fildor did you solve the problem? Because I have the same problem and I don't know how to fix it

Comment: @TomTom I only edited the Question. Original Poster was user Athem

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I mixed up the usernames.
@Athem, any luck with the problem?

Comment: @TomTom Hey! Can I ask you the platform and the OS it is running? In our case, it was linux.